# Invalid variant operation error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

May aim is... I have a xls excel 2003 file... In first colums of first sheet, there are five a two b characters...

With my delphi code, I want to output such that..
This file has 5 a characters, two b characters.....
When I compile and run the program, it gives `Invalid variant operation` ... annoying...
The complete code is given below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComObj, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private { Private declarations }
  public { Public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

var
  uygulama: variant;

var
  i, w: integer; 
 // var str:string; 

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  uygulama := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  uygulama.visible := false;
  uygulama.Workbooks.open['c:\liste.xls'];

  // label1.Caption:=(uygulama.ActiveSheet.cells[1,1]);

  i := 1;
  w := 1;
  repeat
    if uygulama.ActiveSheet.cells[i, 1] = 'a' then
      inc(w);
  until uygulama.ActiveSheet.cells[i, 1] = '';

  Label1.Caption := inttostr(w);

end;

end.
```

Comment: If you used early binding then the compiler would find these errors

Comment: Ignore the above - I've turned my comment into an answer. How does one delete a comment?

Comment: @ No'am Newman Click on the cross that appears when you hover to the right of the comment's time stamp

Comment: You might want to use the [XML SpreadSheet storage format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066.aspx) that has been available since Office XP. It doesn't require Excel to be installed (since it is XML based) and might make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

To access a value from a cell you must use the `value` property

try this

```
  repeat
    if uygulama.ActiveSheet.cells[i, 1].value = 'a' then
      inc(w);
  until uygulama.ActiveSheet.cells[i, 1].value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have now figured out how to get the value of the cell, there are a few points regarding your code which I wish to make.

1. The repeat loop is going to be very slow. It would be better to store the cell's value in a local variable before entering the loop and then perform your counting operation on your local variable.
2. The loop stands a very good chance of being infinite because you're not changing any values which change (apart from w). Why not write something like

   ```
   s:= uygulama.activesheet.cells[i,1].value;
   w:= 0;
   for i:= 1 to length (s) do
     if s[i] = 'a' then inc (w);
   ```